# Can Chrome Driver be ran "headless" like PhantomJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I am writing integration tests with Selenium Web Driver using the Chrome Driver.

I need to run these integration test on the build server.

Can it be ran "headless" or should I recur to PhantomJS? Thank You.

Comment: I dont think what you are asking makes sense. All the selenium drivers do is wrap and automate an existing browser. (eg you cant run chrome in console mode to my knowledge) but you can definitely run chrome on a build server (regardless of if it opens a window)

Comment: All that being said i actually use phantom for tests out of preference :)

Comment: Use XServer to accomplish your task.